# Why does winforms TreeView treenode say 'treenode:' in the node?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Everyone:
   When I run the following code, everything works okay except the words 'TreeNode:' displays with each node when I run the application.  The application is C Sharp Winform .NET 4.0.

Instead of each node saying: 
12345 Date:1/1/1980 - Customer:XYZ

they say:
TreeNode: 12345 Date:1/1/1980 - Customer:XYZ.

I'm using .NET 4.0.  I don't use TreeView a lot but I've never seen this problem with older versions of .NET.

Thanks for the help.
Dale

```
quotesTreeView.BeginUpdate();
quotesTreeView.Nodes.Clear();

for (int i = 0; i < sqmTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (currentQuoteNumber != sqmTable.Rows[i]["QuoteNumber"].ToString())
    {                        
        quotesTreeView.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(sqmTable.Rows[i]["QuoteNumber"].ToString()) + " Date: " + sqmTable.Rows[i]["QuoteDate"].ToString() + " - Customer:" +  sqmTable.Rows[i]["CustomerName"].ToString());

        quotesTreeView.Nodes[masterNodeNumber].Tag = C_MASTER + "," + sqmTable.Rows[i]["QuoteNumber"].ToString();
        quotesTreeView.Nodes[masterNodeNumber].ImageIndex = C_IMAGE_QLOGO;
        quotesTreeView.Nodes[masterNodeNumber].SelectedImageIndex = C_IMAGE_QLOGO;

        currentQuoteNumber = sqmTable.Rows[i]["QuoteNumber"].ToString();
        masterNodeNumber = quotesTreeView.Nodes.Count-1;
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like your datacolumn `QuoteNumber` has prefix `TreeNode:`

Comment: You can set the text for each node in the properties for the control.

Answer (score 1):

This is the implementation of the TreeNode.ToString() method:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return ("TreeNode: " + ((this.text == null) ? "" : this.text));
}
```

So what you saw is no great mystery.  You'll see it in the debugger for example when you inspect a node.  If you actually see it in your UI then a good place to look is in the code that add rows to "sqmTable".  Make sure it uses the node's Text property instead of ToString().